# Relevant css file for main intranet pg

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-library

How to access the relevant CSS file for main intranet page in sps2013.

Sorry i did researched n tried with spd 2013, but cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler2 to get the exact location of the CSS you're interested in. There are multiple CSS files used in SharePoint so Fiddler2 will show all CSS consumed. 
https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Once you identified the CSS file you need, you can edit the file from the SharePoint server in this physical location:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\

Please note that the \15\ changes per version. 
16 = 2016
15 = 2013
14 = 2010
12 = 2007

Comment: Or hit F12 in the Browser and check the Network tab

Comment: Only if you're using Internet Explorer. Fiddler2 is browser agnostic. ;-)

Comment: I must have special versions of Chrome and Firefox then that have F12 as well, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you access SharePoint Designer, you should be able to find all the CSS files under Style folder:
(you can use any tools mentioned above to identify which one is it)

[image]

Sometimes we will attach an alternate CSS file and override the original CSS. So you don't have to find out which CSS is it. 
(Site Setting > Master Page > Alternate CSS URL)

[image]